# insert VBS variable within a single-quoted WMI query

Tags: vbscript

I am really frustrated by the snippet below:

```
Dim objFSO, varSrc, varDest, varExt

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

varSrc = WScript.Arguments(0)
varDest = WScript.Arguments(1)
varExt = WScript.Arguments(2)

If objFSO.FolderExists(varSrc) Then
    WScript.Echo varSrc
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
        ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE " _
            & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' AND " _
                & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
                    & "'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\kk ""'")
    Do
        Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
        WScript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
    Loop
Else
    WScript.Echo "Bazinga"
End If
```

I tried to replace c:\\kk with varSrc however it seems impossible for WSH to recognize it in WMI query - not to mention it was within a single quote!

I have tried chr(34) and it didn't work. Please help if possible. Much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Thank you so much for the answer and apologies for ambiguities.

`varSrc` is supposed to be "`C:\\\\kk`". and the WMI query couldn't recognize it. Let me explain by example:

The query should be parsed in such:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' AND TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name= ""c:\\\\KK""'
```

I have tested the query above and it works! However what I need is to replace `c:\\\\kk` with an argument taken from user input, which in this case, is `varSrc`. The problem I have encountered is either the syntax is correct however WMI Query would be taking `varSrc` literally as the '`Directory.Name`'; Or the other way - the syntax error or unparsable query.

If the query is:

```
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE " _
            & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' AND " _
                & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
                    & "'Win32_Directory.Name=""varSrc""'")
```

The script will run without any error however it's not doing its job monitoring the newly created files. Because it parse the 'Directory.Name' as literal 'varSrc' instead of user-input argument.

If the query is:

```
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE " _
        & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' AND " _
            & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
                & "'Win32_Directory.Name="""""&varSrc&"""""'")
```

It will generate an error:

```
vmove.vbs(15, 2) SWbemServicesEx: Invalid query
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you run this? Also, can you show what that query is supposed to look like? Tip: you should build the query up as a string variable and display it before using it in the query, so you have a clear idea of what you're sending it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, `varSrc` contains the folder path with single backslashes, while your WMI query requires four backslashes as the path separator. Try doing a replace of `\` with `\\\\` in `varSrc` before inserting it into the query, like this:

```
varSrc = Replace(varSrc, "\", "\\")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE " _
        & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
            & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
                & "'Win32_Directory.Name=""" & varSrc & """'")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've just tested it your answer. It works!

Answer (score 1):

Pls. chk below script,

```
varSrc = Replace(varSrc, "\", "\\")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE " _
    & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
        & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
            & "Win32_Directory.Name=" & "'" & varSrc & "'")
```